# Qual é a diferença na prática em usar RIGHT JOIN, em vez de usar LEFT JOIN alterando a ordem das tabelas

Tags: sql, join

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença na prática para usar o RIGHT JOIN, ao invés de apenas alterar a ordem das tabelas e usar o LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Desde que inverta todas as referências de A e B, resulta na mesma coisa. `SELECT tab_tudo LEFT JOIN tab_alguns ON condicao` é  o mesmo que `SELECT tab_alguns RIGHT JOIN tab_tudo ON condicao` (é uma versão "espelhada"). Ou seja, no fim é mera escolha pessoal por organização e legibilidade do que está fazendo.

Answer (score -4):

Digamos que vc tem duas tabelas.
Cliente e Vendas

Se você usar o **Right** onde o **Cliente.id = venda.idcliente** mesmo que não tenha venda vai mostrar cliente. E se usar o **Left** onde o **Cliente.id = venda.idcliente** mesmo que não tenha cliente vai mostrar venda.

Enquanto com **inner join** só vai trazer os registros se tiver valores de ligação nas duas tabelas.

Isso falando rasamente o conceito.

Comment: Mas a pergunta foi sobre a diferença entre usar o RIGHT JOIN e inverter a ordem das tabelas. Consegue editar a resposta para focar só no que foi perguntado?